# How to delete a blank ad slot that occupies space?

Tags: css, responsive, adsense

I have a simple problem with Google Adsense ads. I'm showing 300 x 600 ads. 300 x 600 ads can not be found, so different size ads are showing.

[Ads picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5RUy.png) |
[Ads picture 2](http://prntscr.com/ivyr8h)

I'm reviewing codes when small ads arrive.

```
#google_center_div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I do not want this code to work. What should I do?

Comment: do you mean at the left and right sides?

Comment: No, bottom and top.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ivyr8h

Comment: Try setting it's display as block in your own styles and then add !important to it if required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Use responsive ads. It will occupy space according to devices & will give you higher revenue. All the best. :)